# Evaluate an indefinite integral for an polynomial with negative fractional exponent

Tags: calculus

$$ \int \frac {1}{(3 + 2x - x^2)^{3/2}} dx $$

I am revising calculus by solving problems in Schaum's advanced calc, but can't seem to get an answer for this particular problem. I can't find any trigonometric function to use here. I am not sure how to use partial fractions either.

Comment: Completing the square gives that the parenthetical quantity in the denominator is $4 - (x - 1)^2$, which suggests the substitution $x - 1 = 2 \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints;
Write $$-x^2+2x+3=4-(x-1)^2$$

Substitute $u=x-1$ and then $u=2\sin(s)$

Comment: Yes this worked. I end up with tan theta with the limits changed to accommodate the transformations.